# How to create primary key constraint on H2 with same pk index name?

Tags: sql, h2

While creating tables in h2. H2 Primary index name auto-generated. I want my primary key constraint and primary key index name same, so that I can get an exception with predefined constraint violation.

```sql
CREATE TABLE roles (
    id int NOT NULL,
    rolename varchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT "pk_role_id" PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Above code creates an index with name PRIMARY_KEY_4. I want this index name same as constraint name.

Altering name after creation is not an option as index name in inconsistent.

I tried using various option but as soon as I create primary key constraints new index is created.

Comment: Old unsupported H2 1.4.178 (released in 2014) and all newer versions don't show names of indexes on primary key violations, they throw `Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.ROLES(ID)"` instead. You use some entirely outdated version of H2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use H2, but - reading discussion titled [does index created automatically for primary key and unique constraints](https://groups.google.com/g/h2-database/c/Hi_JnOPM9vI), I'd say that you **can** do what you asked.

This is Oracle (not H2), but it'll illustrate what I'm trying to say.

First, create table with no constraints:

```
SQL> create table roles
  2    (id         int          not null,
  3     rolename   varchar(20)
  4    );

Table created.
```

Now, create unique index (must be unique because primary key won't allow duplicates); name it `pk_roles`:

```
SQL> create unique index pk_roles on roles (id);

Index created.
```

Finally, add primary key constraint. As index - on a primary key column, `id` - already exists, database will use it:

```
SQL> alter table roles add constraint pk_roles primary key (id);

Table altered.
```

To check whether primary key constraint and index - that supports it - really have the same name, I'll query data dictionary view:

```
SQL> select table_name, constraint_name, index_name
  2  from user_constraints
  3  where table_name = 'ROLES';

TABLE_NAME                     CONSTRAINT_NAME                INDEX_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
ROLES                          PK_ROLES                       PK_ROLES
```

Right; that's *it*.

---

Once again: this is Oracle so I can only hope that H2 works the same way, according to discussion whose link is posted at beginning of this answer.

---

Bonus: Oracle lets you explicitly specify which index will be used; I'll drop the primary key constraint ...

```
SQL> alter table roles drop constraint pk_roles;

Table altered.
```

... and recreate it with additional `using index` clause:

```
SQL> alter table roles add constraint pk_roles primary key (id) using index pk_roles;

Table altered.
```

Doing so, you don't have to rely on database *implicitly* using index which was pre-created, but have control over it and actually *see* instruction you gave to the database.

A quick look at [H2 commands](https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html) says that there's no such clause there, though.

Comment: I tried doing above step but as soon as you hit alter table roles add constraint pk_roles primary key (id); command it creates new index. My use case is solved by renaming index created by h2, but I want to create to achieve that in some generic way (while renaming I will have to read index name created by h2)

Comment: I see; so, H2 allows you to double-index the same column? Once by your own index, and another time by H2 while adding the primary key constraint. That's interesting. Oracle (database I use) won't let you do that; it'll raise `ORA-01408: such column list already indexed`. Well, that's bad, I was hoping that it would work ...